# Marshal.ReleaseComObject and return values

Tags: .net, com-interop

I'm looking for ideas managing the lifetime of COM objects created in a .Net assembly that are then passed back to unmanaged code.

Background:
Our software engine is coded in unmanaged c++. The functionality of our software is expandable using COM object components for the engine. For the most part, the engine itself hasn't needed to change for years. However we continue to build more components to add new features to our software. While these components used to be built in unmanaged c++ as well, for the past couple years we have been coding these plugins in C#.

Until recently, we have subscribed to the idea Marshal.ReleaseComObject should not be called on the unmanaged COM objects used in the C# components and instead allow the RCW and garbage collection manage their lifetime.

This theory sounds good, but in practice we have begun having memory issues with our software that seems to be caused by GC being lazy about cleaning up these COM objects to the point that in some cases our software will use up all available memory and fail.

Is there some mistake we might be making that is preventing the GC and RCW from acting on this objects? Isn't the idea of garbage collection that it will do what is necessary to make sure memory is free when needed?

For lack of any better ideas, we have reluctantly begun making use of Marshal.ReleaseComObject (and in some cases FinalReleaseComObject). In general, this does seem to do the trick.

However, in trying to develop a consistent pattern for using Marshal.ReleaseComObject we have found one case in which we are not sure it is possible to use it. Some components need to pass COM object return values back to the unmanaged engine. The component will never see the return value again and (currently) has no way of being notified when it is no longer being used. For example:

```
// Unmanaged C++ code
Engine::Engine() : m_ipDoodadCreator(CLSID_FancyComponent)
{
}
void Engine::ProcessDoodad()
{
    try
    {
        // Smart pointer
        IDoodadPtr ipDoodad = m_ipDoodadCreator->CreateDoodad();
        ...
        ipDoodad = NULL; // Calls Release...
    }
    catch (...) { ... }
    // At this point the doodad lives on because the RCW is holding a
    // reference to it.
}

// Managed C# Component
public class FancyComponent : IDoodadCreator
{
    public IDoodad IDoodadCreator.CreateDoodad()
    {
        // IDoodad is implmented in unmanaged c++
        IDoodad doodad = new IDoodad();

        try
        {
            ...

            return doodad;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Can't do this here because engine doesn't yet have
            // a reference to doodad.
            // Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doodad);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, the only idea we can come up with in order to deterministically get the RCW to release its reference in this situation would be to re-work the engine so that all the interfaces have a Cleanup() call that is called from time to time, but that would be time consuming and, in some cases, quite cumbersome to implement.

**tl;dr** Is there a way to force the RCW to release its reference to a COM object that is being returned into an unmanaged environment?

Comment: `IDoodad` should Inherit from `IUnknown` so you should be able to call `Release` normally last I checked

Comment: Release decrements the reference count. If something else (the RCW) still has a reference, doodad continues to live. In the above code, I am implying IDoodadPtr is a smart pointer that is calling Release when it goes out of scope.

Comment: You mean a [COM Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)? according to MSDN if release is called normally it will release the object for garbage collection.

Comment: Yes, I don't dispute that it is eligible for garbage collection. But that garbage collection doesn't always seem to be happening in time. This is why we are attempting to intervene in the form of a call to ReleaseComObject. But how to do so when the object is a return value?
EDIT: If I have my RCW and CCW's straight, I think it is an Runtime Callable Wrapper we are talking about here, not a CCW since a Doodad is an unmananaged c++ COM object in my example.

Comment: Try manually managing the lifetime for a debugging session, see what `Release` is returning when you would expect all other references to be released. Most likely `AddRef` is getting called once too many times.

Comment: That's a good thought and I will investigate that possibility more. But I also discount it because in the cases where the engine is using a c++ component, we don't have this issue and if ReleaseComObject is called before returning from the .Net component, the engine fails with the error "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used". This shows the managed side had only the one reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to our immediate issue is GC.AddMemoryPressure.

Because we are creating and referencing via the RCW instances of un-managed classes, the garbage collector is unaware of the memory allocated for those objects. 
As per MSDN help on this method:

> In determining when to schedule garbage collection, the runtime takes into account how much managed memory is allocated. If a small managed object allocates a large amount of unmanaged memory, the runtime takes into account only the managed memory, and thus underestimates the urgency of scheduling garbage collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx

In other words, it's not that we need to explicitly release the COM objects... we just need to tell the GC how much memory is associated with them. Indeed, after implementing use of this method in some critical places, the garbage collector is behaving much better.

Comment: I don't post often, but it seems like it would be good etiquette to add a comment explaining why you down-voted an answer so the author can understand what is incorrect/unhelpful...

Answer (score 1):

> but in practice we have begun having memory issues with our software

This is a classic growing-pain problem.  Software never gets smaller, nobody in the team is awarded for writing *negative code*.  Add more and more features, your program never ever uses *less* memory.  A standard diagnostic is that consuming the first gigabyte of virtual memory space took a very long time.  The second gigabyte disappeared really quickly.

Where you are now is *very* unproductive, you are fretting over a handful of megabytes.  Just flip the switch to not-a-problem.  Compile the native code to 64-bit.  You won't get any objection from the managed code, the x64 jitter already knows how to do that without *any* changes.

Comment: I think you are right in that we need to look for other strategies. One we used not too long ago was to turn on the large address aware flag. But while going to x64 may not be "unproductive" in that that we would be deriving long-term benefit, it is also nowhere close to easy and not something we can make time for to address the immediate issue at hand; we have a lot of legacy c++ code where the choice of types was not done with an eventual move to x64 in mind...

Answer (score 1):

I have determined two possible solutions. Both involve changed the *managed* definition of your COM interface, though you do not need to change your *unmanaged* code at all.

1. Define your return value as `IntPtr`. Then, when your managed method is ready to return, acquire an `IntPtr` from your COM object via `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject()`. At that point, you can safely call 'Marshal.ReleaseComObject()' on your COM object.

```cs
    public interface IDoodadCreator
    {
        IntPtr IDoodadCreator.CreateDoodad();
    }

    public class FancyComponent : IDoodadCreator
    {
        public IntPtr IDoodadCreator.CreateDoodad()
        {
            // IDoodad is implemented in unmanaged c++
            IDoodad doodad = new IDoodad();
            ...
    
            IntPtr doodadPtr = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(doodad);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doodad);
            return doodadPtr;
        }
    }
```

OR

2. Define your return value as `object`, and define the interface to use a custom marshaler that releases the object after marshaling it to an IntPtr.

```cs
    public interface IDoodadCreator
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(ReleasingMarshaler))]
        object IDoodadCreator.CreateDoodad();
    }

    public class FancyComponent : IDoodadCreator
    {
        public object IDoodadCreator.CreateDoodad()
        {
            // IDoodad is implemented in unmanaged c++
            IDoodad doodad = new IDoodad();
            ...
    
            return doodad;
        }
    }

    public class ReleasingMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
    {
        ...

        public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
        {
            IntPtr managedObjPtr = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(managedObj);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(managedObj);
            return managedObjPtr;
        }
    }
```